# Java ImageView coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, screen, coordinates

i am trying to make support remote desktop software and i need to use Robot to do like mouse click and stuff like that and my problem is that i want Robot.mousemove that needs screen coordinates X and Y and i dont know how to get that from imageview when my mouse is moving on the imageview soo i tried this:

```
    double screenx = 0;
    double screeny = 0;
    RemoteDekstopFormDesktopImageView.localToScreen(screenx, screeny);
```

But it returns me 0.0 BUT also it should see what the screen size actually is also right? soo lets say the screen size is 1280x1024 soo we need to get the coordinates from the image view that would also calculate from screen resolution! well its very hard to explain but you get it what i am trying to achieve right? if you dont know what just look up what remote desktop is for example: teamviewer software. Thanks! i only need to get the x and y coordinates!

Also i almost forgot i am using JavaFX latest version.

Comment: Why the dislike? it is a good question for people that wants to make remote dekstop control because there is no tutorials online how to do it! this should help some people

Comment: Good news i did find out that we can find imageview coordinates using mouseevent.getX(); and stuff like that now i need to calculate the screen size also and it will be fixed while you guys are just being lazy

Answer (score 0):

GREAT NEWS! I was able to convert the code i found to javafx and it works! this is how it works: for people that want to get real coordinates from imageview

You need to get the monitor size and imageview size then you set x like this:

```
imgmousex = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()/RemoteDekstopFormDesktopImageView.getFitWidth();
```

Width is X and then the same with Y that is Height:

```
imgmousey = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()/RemoteDekstopFormDesktopImageView.getFitHeight();
```

And then the final step is you need to convert it to coordinates we will do this:

```
event.getX() * imgmousex
event.getY() * imgmouseY
```

this will get you the coordinates even is the mouseevent and imgmousex or imgmousey is lets say fake coordinates that we set up. I cant explain very well but i hope you understand this its very easy when you understand it. Thanks for everyone that tried to help me but didn't post anything! I hope this will help a lot of people that needs real coordinates!

Answer (score 0):

And why did you not just use one of the localToScreen or screenToLocal transformation methods built into every Node?

Comment: I did try it but it always returned null to me